# Taking minimum value of each entry +- 10 rows either side in numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, minimum

I have a 3d numpy array and want to generate a secondary array consisting of the minimum of each value and the values in the 10 rows directly above and 10 rows directly below (i.e each entry is the minimum value from 21 values) for each 2d array.

I've been trying to use 'numpy.clip' to deal with the edges of the array - here the range of values which the minimum is taken from should simply reduce to 10 at the values on the top/bottom of the array. I think something like 'scipy.signal.argrelmin' seems to be what I'm after.

Here's my code so far, definitely not the best way to go about it:

```
import numpy as np

array_3d = np.random.random_integers(50, 80, (3, 50, 18))
minimums = np.zeros(array_3d.shape)

for array_2d_index in range(len(array_3d)):
    for row_index in range(len(array_3d[array_2d_index])):
        for col_index in range(len(array_3d[array_2d_index][row_index])):
            minimums[array_2d_index][row_index][col_index] = min(array_3d[array_2d_index][np.clip(row_index-10, 0, 49):np.clip(row_index+10, 0, 49)][col_index])
```

The main issue I think is that this is taking the minimum from the columns either side of each entry instead of the rows, which has been giving index errors.

Would appreciate any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
def strided_3D_axis1(array_3d, L):
    s0,s1,s2 = array_3d.strides
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided 
    m,n,r = array_3d.shape
    nL = n-L+1
    return strided(array_3d, (m,nL,L,r),(s0,s1,s1,s2))

out = strided_3D_axis1(array_3d, L=21).min(axis=-2)
```

Sample run -

1) Input :

```
In [179]: array_3d
Out[179]: 
array([[[73, 65, 51, 76, 59],
        [74, 57, 75, 53, 70],
        [60, 74, 52, 54, 60],
        [54, 52, 62, 75, 50],
        [68, 56, 68, 63, 77]],

       [[62, 70, 60, 79, 74],
        [70, 68, 50, 74, 57],
        [63, 57, 69, 65, 54],
        [63, 63, 68, 58, 60],
        [70, 66, 65, 78, 78]]])
```

2) Strided view :

```
In [180]: strided_3D_axis1(array_3d, L=3)
Out[180]: 
array([[[[73, 65, 51, 76, 59],
         [74, 57, 75, 53, 70],
         [60, 74, 52, 54, 60]],

        [[74, 57, 75, 53, 70],
         [60, 74, 52, 54, 60],
         [54, 52, 62, 75, 50]],

        [[60, 74, 52, 54, 60],
         [54, 52, 62, 75, 50],
         [68, 56, 68, 63, 77]]],


       [[[62, 70, 60, 79, 74],
         [70, 68, 50, 74, 57],
         [63, 57, 69, 65, 54]],

        [[70, 68, 50, 74, 57],
         [63, 57, 69, 65, 54],
         [63, 63, 68, 58, 60]],

        [[63, 57, 69, 65, 54],
         [63, 63, 68, 58, 60],
         [70, 66, 65, 78, 78]]]])
```

3) Strided view based `min` :

```
In [181]: strided_3D_axis1(array_3d, L=3).min(axis=-2)
Out[181]: 
array([[[60, 57, 51, 53, 59],
        [54, 52, 52, 53, 50],
        [54, 52, 52, 54, 50]],

       [[62, 57, 50, 65, 54],
        [63, 57, 50, 58, 54],
        [63, 57, 65, 58, 54]]])
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) upon creating all sliding indices along the second axis -

```
array_3d[:,np.arange(array_3d.shape[1]-L+1)[:,None] + range(L)].min(-2)
```

**Approach #3**

Here's another using [`Scipy's 1D minimum filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter1d as minf

L = 21
hL = (L-1)//2
out = minf(array_3d,L,axis=1)[:,hL:-hL]
```

---

**Runtime test -**

```
In [231]: array_3d = np.random.randint(50, 80, (3, 50, 18))

In [232]: %timeit strided_3D_axis1(array_3d, L=21).min(axis=-2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 54.2 µs per loop

In [233]: %timeit array_3d[:,np.arange(array_3d.shape[1]-L+1)[:,None] + range(L)].min(-2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 81.3 µs per loop

In [234]: L = 21
     ...: hL = (L-1)//2
     ...: 

In [235]: %timeit minf(array_3d,L,axis=1)[:,hL:-hL]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tested these and found that if a minimum value (e.g. 50 in the randint) is at the edge of the array (e.g in the bottom row) then the 10 values directly above are not equal to 50 and are instead higher.

Comment: @JGraham353 With all three approaches?

Comment: Also, 'L' should be set to 11 to only allow the range of values to be 10 rows directly above and 10 rows directly below the given value?

Comment: Yes, they seemed to work for the centre parts of the array but would give incorrect values towards the edges.

Comment: @JGraham353 So, for the edge elements, for which we won't have the window of 10 rows and below, you want to consider as many are available, right? For example, for the last row, we would only have that row itself and the 10 rows above it, i.e. it would only try to find the minimum in 11 rows available to it. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @JGraham353 Then, simply use the last approach without the slicing : `minf(array_3d,21,axis=1)`.

Comment: Hi Divakar. I wasn't sure if I should have asked this as a new question. I am looking for an equivalent method of finding the mean of each value in the array with the 20 values in rows above & 20 values in rows below (i.e. 41 total values). I've been trying to use Scipy's 'uniform_filter1d', but the 'modes' which deal with the edges of the array cannot accomplish what you confirmed in your 2nd last comment. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: @JGraham353 I think a new question would be a better idea.