# How to efficiently compute moving average in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, mean

I am looking for a way of calculating the mean of each given value in a 3d Numpy array with the 20 values in rows directly above and 20 values in rows directly below. This is similar to a previous question I asked ([Taking minimum value of each entry +- 10 rows either side in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032403/taking-minimum-value-of-each-entry-10-rows-either-side-in-numpy-array)) but calculating the mean of 41 values instead of the minimum of 21 values.

I have tried using [Scipy's uniform 1d filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html), but this does not have a mode which deals with the values close to the edge of the array correctly. The window which is outside of the array should not be included in  the mean calculation (i.e. at the bottom/top locations in the array the mean should be taken from the edge value and the 20 rows above/below respectively).

Is there any way of using the uniform filter, or is there an alternative method which achieves this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The Numpy array has dimensions 20x3200x18, so I was looking for a relatively efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really looking for performance in this, you can exploit `cumsum` in order to only have to calculate the sums once, this should make the implementation about 40 times faster.

See below for an example. Without your exact data and a reference implementation I cannot verify that this does exactly what you want, but it should be correct in spirit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.rand(20, 3200, 18)
n = 20

cumsum = np.cumsum(arr, axis=1)

means_lower = cumsum[:, :n, :] / np.arange(1, n + 1)[None, :, None]
means_middle = (cumsum[:, 2 * n:, :] - cumsum[:, :-2 * n , :]) / (2 * n)
means_upper = (cumsum[:, -1, :][:, None, :] - cumsum[:, -n - 1:-1, :]) / np.arange(n, 0, -1)[None, :, None]

means = np.concatenate([means_lower, means_middle, means_upper], axis=1)

x = np.arange(3200)

plt.plot(x, means[0, :, 0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.signal.convolve` to do this.

```
import scipy.signal as sig

def windowed_mean(arr, n):
    dims = len(arr.shape)
    s = sig.convolve(arr, np.ones((2*n+1,)*dims), mode='same')
    d = sig.convolve(np.ones_like(arr), np.ones((2*n+1,)*dims), mode='same')
    return s/d
```

Basically, `s` is a windowed sum and `d` is a windowed counter, so you avoid errors at the edge

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I should have mentioned that the array is large (20x3200x18), so I'm not sure a convolve operation is the best solution for me.

Comment: For large arrays, `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` is faster. Note that this function does a circular convolution, which will give you different behavior from `scipy.signal.convolve` at the edges.